# Select the table name as a column in a UNION select query in MySQL

Tags: mysql, union

I want to be able to select the name of a the table a row is from as a column in a union select query. Something like this:

```
SELECT [TABLENAME], text from table1
UNION
SELECT [TABLENAME], text from table2
ORDER BY date
```

Does anyone know if this is possible?
Thanks

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You are already querying on that table itself. Eg:- table1 and table2

So you can basically output table name as string itself -

```
SELECT 'table1' as tableName, text from table1
UNION
SELECT 'table2' as tableName, text from table2
ORDER BY date
```

Answer (score 1):

given that you've got to type the table name into the sql anyway, why not just include it as a string in the select too?  i.e.

```
SELECT 'table1' as tablename, text from table1
UNION
SELECT 'table2' as tablename, text from table2
ORDER BY date
```