# Can I, in a union select, somehow exclude a column from the comparison test?

Tags: sql

This is a more general version of question [Can I include a table name in a union select](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4266164/select-the-table-name-as-a-column-in-a-union-select-query-in-mysql), but the answers given there are wrong (from the point of view of *my* needs) in the sense that they force `UNION ALL` semantics rather than `UNION`.

Motivation:
let's imagine a 'table per concrete class' class hierarchy mapping of animals (where every table contains just the 'extra' columns).

Let's take two queries I would like to have a 'logical union' of:

1. `SELECT animal.*, squirrelBits.* from animals join squirrelBits on (...)`
2. `SELECT animal.*, hamsterBits.* from animals join hamsterBits on (...)`

I can add a null column for every `hamsterBits` column to the squirrel query and vice versa. In the application, each query mentioned here is associated with a compatible result set reader - lets assume for now they are smart enough to ignore any null columns they doesn't know about. Naturally, as in the quoted question, I'd like to introduce a column which would tell me in the application whether a row is a squirrel or a hamster. Now, because a hamster cannot be a squirrel, these queries have disjoint result sets, so I can, as stated in the answer to the above, add a column `'squirrel' as species` to the first one and `'hamster' as species` to the second one, and create a result set reader which checks the 'species' column and uses the appropriate one of the former readers.

My problem is that I am writing generic code which doesn't understand the concept of class to table mappings and should work for any queries: look at the select clauses, add missing columns as null to each one, and then simply label them 'query1' and 'query2'.
For now, still good.

Next two pair of queries, built as above:

1. a union of hamsters and squirrels,
2. a union of hamsters and elephants

Now, these queries *can* have a non empty intersection; adding a discriminator column
will no longer perform a true union unless I somehow guarantee that all columns except for 'species' is a key, and 'species' depends on it. The proper way to address this would be to associate with each reader a 'species name' which should be used in such cases, track the existence of a discriminator column, reuse it in multi-compound selects *and* ensure that hamsters are always labeled as 'hamster', so that 'logical' hamster duplicates are indeed equal to each other on all columns, including the discriminator.

It is the last bit that is truly problematic, because, as I said, this should work for any queries, including, for example,

```
SELECT animal.*, <extra columns> FROM animals where (...)
```

where `<extra columns>` is the exact column list from `hamsterBits` with default literal values. I have no way of enforcing that the user creating such a query will say it's a hamster, and trying to force such a requirement will be quite brittle. If I am facing the risk of different 'species'/'discriminator' column value for otherwise identical rows anyway, then I would rather try to make it the normal behaviour. With a very careful design this might be doable.

My life would be much easier hoewver, if I could attach some 'meta' information to every row telling me from which of the original non-compound selects it came, *which will be ignored when checking for duplicates* - I don't care which reader I'll use if the rows are equal, so I don't care the row with which of that meta information is preserved and which one is discarded.

Is it doable? In what standard/vendor specific extensions?

Comment: Well, bit of an odd dillema.  But there are some environments where a `UNION` or `UNION ALL` isn't even allowed. In such cases a `FULL JOIN` could be an alternative.

Comment: `FULL JOIN` is certainly a worthwile idea to think about. I'm a bit hesitant though, as my query generating code is otherwise very WYSIWYG, and changing `select1 union select2`  into some `select ... from select1 outer join select2` would be surprising to the programmer.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe try to create an additional table with meta data.
But that also has its own nuances for example meta information will take up additional space.

1. `SELECT animal.*, squirrelBits.*, metainfo.type  from animals join squirrelBits on (...) join metainfo on(...)`
2. `SELECT animal.*, hamsterBits.*, metainfo.type from animals join hamsterBits on (...) join metainfo on(...)`

In the example above, you can get meta data for each type after UNION

And if queries are not generated automatically, but are written, maybe adding static meta is a not bad idea?

1. `SELECT animal.*, squirrelBits.*, 'Squirrel Bits' from animals join squirrelBits on (...)`
2. `SELECT animal.*, hamsterBits.*, 'Hamster Bits' from animals join hamsterBits on (...)`

Comment: Sorry for coming late, the browser was showing me cached data. Upped for a nice idea, although queries *are* generated automatically. Still, these queries could possibly be preceeded by creation of temporary  tables, so it's not impossible.

Comment: Thinking more about it, and while it isn't yet a solution, you put me on the right track: every query could include a discriminator, and we'd put these in a `WITH` clause; then `select1 UNION select2` would become `WITH select1, select2 ((SELECT <everything but species> FROM select1)  UNION (SELECT <everything but species> FROM select2)) JOIN (SELECT id, species FROM (select1 UNION ALL select2) USING id`.  This is still very rough - it needs to know the key of every query, and possibly somehow handle cases where the keys are different. I also wonder what the performance penalty would be.